# Может ли пользователь Android быть уверенным в безопасности?

Tags: android, безопасность, ос, права-доступа

Я как пользователь ОС не разбираюсь в безопасности, хотя знаю базовые концепции криптографии и сертификатов. Сейчас стараюсь не скачивать приложения от не очень известных компаний и не давать доступ приложениям без надобности. При поисках доступного описания обычно встречаются поверхностные советы или глубокое описание для разработчиков которое сложно понять за короткий срок. Поэтому хочу спросить тех кто уже в этом хорошо разбирается:

1. Как отделить приложения от своих данных?
   Некоторые приложения могут запрашивать права на доступ к файловой системе, при том не всегда просто понять что конкретно будет позволено. Где мне хранить важную информацию на телефоне к которой не должно быть доступа у других приложений? На Windows в крайнем случае я могу запускать приложения на виртуалке без опасения за данные. На Android такой возможности я не помню.
   Что с буфером обмена, доступен ли он приложениям по умолчанию? Могу ли я копировать пароли без опасения?
   Если я использую не файловую систему для важной информации, а гугл диск на телефоне, то мне не нужно беспокоиться за другие приложения на устройстве?
2. Приложения по умолчанию имеют доступ к своему серверу и часто без него не работают. К примеру часто могут запрашивать разрешение к фото и видео... То есть они могут отправить мои личные данные на сервер без проблем? Аналогично и с контактами?
3. Бывает что приходят СМС из банка и автоматически происходит подставление кода в приложение банка. Каким образом происходит связка приложения банка с этим СМС? Может ли другое приложение похитить данные подставив их себе? Бывает такое что приложения просят доступ к контактам и СМС, значит они могут иметь доступ к таким кодам?
4. Какие проблемы могут возникнуть с рут правами?
5. Существует много новых китайских компаний со своими модификациями Android, стоит ли ставить чистый Android для безопасности? Несут ли вообще такие модификации опасность?
6. Что еще может быть важно для безопасности на Android?

Comment: Это слишком много больших вопросов для одного вопроса.

Comment: 4-6  не очень важно ответить, а другие тоже много затрагивают. Но это основные вопросы которые интересны пользователю, хотелось бы хоть частями получить ответ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. По сути никак. Каждое приложение работает в своей песочнице. У каждого приложения есть свое хранилище данных. Но так же приложение может пользоваться и "общими данными", которые хранятся на вашем устройстве. Но для доступа к ним, приложение должно запросить явный доступ у пользователя. Если вы ему предоставили этот доступ - то что оно с ними делает вы не узнаете. Никто кроме разработчиков приложения этот код не знает и вы можете либо доверять разработчику.

   Все что вы можете - это если вы не доверяете приложению - не давать разрешение. Или же после каждого использования фичи (например загрзки фото) отключать разрешение на чтение/запись. В Android 11 будут еще One Time Permission суть которых в том, чтоб давать разрешение приложению только единоразово. Например если у вас приложение для заказа суши и вы просто для профиля хотите загрузить свою аватарку то вам совершенно не нужно давать приложению доступ к файлам на постоянной основе.
2. Все данные которые находятся во внутренней песочнице приложения - это его данные и любое приложение имеет к ним беспрепятсвенный доступ. А значит оно может спокойно отправлять их куда угодно до тех пор пока приложение не выгружено из памяти. И тут опять только вопрос доверия разработчику.
3. Если вы даете разрешение на чтение смс приложению то оно может их читать и делать с этими данными то что ему нужно. Другие приложения этого сделать бесприпятственно не смогут.
4. Если вы сделаете рут на вашем телефоне, то вы даете доступ к вашим личным файлам всем приложениям. Т.е. принцип "Песочницы" уже работать не будет. Это не значит, что вы сразу же поймаете какую-нибудь дрянь на телефон, но это значит, что если кто-то захочет получить ваши личные данные из банковского приложения, то он без особых проблем сможет сделать это извне.
5. Только вопрос доверия. Нет никаких гарантий того что Google не собирает ваши личные данные (более того, он собирает, но вероятнее всего для общей статистики).
6. Стоит всегда обращать внимания на те разрешения которые запрашивает приложение. Условно если приложение "Фонарик" запрашивает доступ к микрофону стоит задуматься. Не стоит на рутованном телефоне хранить реально конфиденциальные данные. Если вы не доверяете разработчику - то лучше не ставьте его приложение.

А по сути вы ничего не можете с этим сделать. Потому что условно даже если Google не хранит у себя ваши номера карт и пароли, то это могут сделать разработчики Java/Kotlin на уровне компилятора. А если не они, то это могут сделать разработчики компилаторов C++. Проверить это на 100% нереально. Поэтому все здесь упирается в доверие.

Comment: Пункт 2 - вероятно имеется в виду само приложение, а не любое приложение. Пункт 4 - а для рутовых действий не должен постоянно выдаваться запрос? У меня AndroidTV с 9м андроидом спрашиавает подтверждения на рутовые действия с возможностью выбрать, даю я разрегшение на 1 раз, 15 (или другое количество) минут или навсегда: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fucj.png

Comment: Довольно глупый ответ, всегда есть свободная альтернатива без слежки + ты сам можешь проверить исходный код и узнать не следит ли приложение за тобой или если ты не разбираешься в программировании то тогда можете посмотреть на аудиты экспертов в этом.

Comment: NNL993, проверить можно, но ... думаю понятно в чем тут проблема, обчно даже соглашение не читаем, а тут код каждого приложения прошерстить лично. Плюс в таком случае не только проверка кода нужна, а целый протокол как такие проверки ПО устраивать. Есть ли организации, которые системно следят за приложениями и публикуют резульаты проверок, я не заню. Даже если есть, то все еще могут быть вопросы доверия к ним. Но как для пользователя какой тут должен быть совет? Искать в гугле "аудиты экспертов безопасности для _", а если нет такого, то и приложение не использовать?

Answer (score 3):

1. Наиболее безопасным местом для хранения данных являются т.н. приватный каталог приложения (обычно находится в каталоге `/data/data/[пакет приложения]` или с точки зрения прогера доступен через вызов API `Context.getFilesDir()`, правда с двумя оговорками:

   - если нет рута
   - если приложение не предоставило доступ к этому каталогу через `android:sharedUserId`

Понять куда приложение складывает свои данные действительно непросто, могу порекомендовать сканирование APK через [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload), он хорошо раскладывает Android приложение включая наличие `sharedUserId` и детализированные разрешения. Наиболее безопасной сейчас является старшая версия Android 10 - советую обращать внимание на него. Наименее безопасными представляются таки версии ниже 6.0

Буфер обмена доступен практически всем, не советую им пользоваться.

2. Легко могут отправлять. Смотрите за разрешениями на доступ к файловой системе и на чтение контактов.
3. СМС доступен практически всем - на чтение то уж точно. Технически перехватить СМС очень легко, подменить уже сложнее. Когда приходит СМС Android рассылает т.н. `Broadcast` - широковещательное извещение, которое может получить и прочитать любое приложение с разрешением на чтение СМС. Приложение может получив `Broadcast` прочитать сообщение, но подменить сложно. Можно подменить при наличии явного разрешения юзера на использование приложения как дефолтного обработчика СМС - выкинув сообщения типа такого на экран:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4. Рут позволяет получить неограниченный доступ в защищенный раздел памяти (см. п.1), то есть вы тем самым снимаете защиту которую предоставляет Ось. Именно поэтому, в телефонах с рутом многие банковские приложения уже не работают.
5. Главное, чтобы сам девайс был сертифицирован Google. [Список сертифицированных производителей здесь](https://www.android.com/certified/partners/)
6. Самой защищенной областью таки является криптографически защищенное хранилище (лучше всего аппаратное), например Knox в Samsung'ах.

P.S. Специально не рассмотрены всякие разные экзотические способы, описанные Сноуденом & Co, понятно, что кому-надо те всегда найдут способ - самый простой из которых [терморектальный криптоанализатор](http://lurkmore.to/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80)

Comment: Я не согласен с 5-ым ответом, нельзя доверять такой компании как Google т.к. преимущественно Google хочет блага для себя, а не для пользователя, я веду к тому что какой-нибудь из девайсов сертифицированных Google может иметь больше дыр в железе **к примеру**, и соответственно учитывая что Google работает с правительством, пазлы складываются и получается что у спецслужб больше возможностей следить за пользователем, если я не прав прошу свои извинения.

Answer (score 0):

**Здравствуйте!** Ну тут и вопросов... **Предупреждаю!** Я не супер эксперт в андроиде и могу ошибаться, но надеюсь ответить правильно, если будут какие-либо ошибки прошу меня поправить во избежание распространения ложных данных.

Первый вопрос разделю на несколько частей для удобного просмотра.

1.0. Рекомендую к установке какую-либо свободную прошивку для Андроида по типу Replicant, LunaOS, Plasma Mob и т.п., чтобы проприетарные приложения встроенные в прошивку не могли следить за вами, также к замене или полному удалению идут все проприетарные приложения пользователя, свободные приложения вы можете найти в магазине приложений [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org)(Все приложения бесплатные и свободные), а для защиты данных рекомендую [Secure File Manager Beta](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.securefilemanager.app/) - имеется функция шифрования файлов по AES256 + все важные для вас файлы могут пойти в "скрытую" директорию, но на деле она находится по такому пути: */hidden_path*, но в основном(90%+) приложения не имеют прав просматривать, а уж тем более редактировать данные находящиеся там.

1.1. Насчёт буфера обмена сказать не могу, тут я не эксперт, но 100% знаю что встроенные приложения(по типу Google, Yandex и т.д.) в пропретарные прошивки постоянно мониторят буфер обмена и любая информация попавшая в него сразу отправляется на сервера плохих людей.

1.2. Тогда Нужно звенеть во все колокола, **ОСОБОЕННО** такая компания как Google(включаются почти любые облачные хранилища Yandex.Disk, Apple iCloud, Mega и т.д.) следит за всеми вашими данными и их определённо опасно там хранить.

2. Более того, они это **ДЕЛАЮТ**, 99% всех приложений в проприетарных магазинах приложений(по типу Google Play, Apple App Store, Samsung Galaxy Store, Huawei/Honor App Gallery и т.д.) имеют трекеры, чуть более продвинутые свои встроенные [парсеры](https://wikiless.org/wiki/Parsing) которые постоянно собирают информацию пользователя и отправляю эти данные.
3. Тут беспокоится за данные нужно, но не из-за приложений, приложения всего лишь взаимодействуют с Application Manager-ов(Менеджером приложений) с которым сам пользователь и взаимодействует в основном, а вот с сим картой работает уже провайдер и то что ПРОВАЙДЕР захочет, то и будет, но в защиту операторам множество злоумышленников тоже могут получать доступ к девайсам и могут получить почти полный удалённый доступ к телефону жертвы, если у жертвы конечно есть сим карта и в защиту злоумышленникам операторы(и плохие люди которые над ними стоят) этим пользуются и да насчёт приложений, они, если им предоставить доступ могут просмотреть и СМС и контакты.
4. По идее никаких проблем не должно быть, т.к. рут права всего лишь дают вам права супер пользователя, а вот процесс получения этих рут прав буквально может превратить ваш телефон в никому не нужный кирпич, к примеру может отвалиться звук или и того хуже сеть.
5. Не рекомендую делать ни первое, ни второе т.к. и чистый Андроид следит за вами и модифицированный китайскими программистами тоже следит за вами, только у него добавляются ещё и свои трекеры.
6. Во-первых, в файле **hosts** нужно занести все вредоносные и следящие сайты, во вторых нужно самому мониторить свою сеть и смотреть нет и опасных подключений, по-хорошему ещё и нужно использовать blockchain для того чтобы не спалить свой ip-адрес, DNSCrypt, прокси Socks5, Сеть Tor и I2P, DNS Over HTTPS и т.д. и т.п.

В общем по моему скромному мнению это довольно содержательный и достаточно короткий(да, я серьёзно) ответ на вопрос по безопасности на Android/Linux-based системе, конечно было упущено невероятное множество важных деталей, но тогда легче будет написать целый пост в интернете(а обычно их делят, чтобы задержать пользователя на сайте в поисках полного ответа для получения большей прибыли с рекламы, именно поэтому я сказал **ЦЕЛЫЙ** пост) чем ответ на каком-то форуме, надеюсь мой ответ был кому-то полезен.